# pdflatex fails within Emacs.app, but works in terminal

Tags: emacs, auctex, mac, paths

I'm running OS X 10.7 with Emacs 24, Auctex 11.86 and TexLive 2011 via MacTex.

When i run LaTeX through Emacs in the terminal it outputs my `test.tex` as `test.pdf` just fine.

However, when i run the same file through Auctex in Emacs.app it fails and I'm given:

```
LaTex: problems after [0] pages'
```

and the output reads

```
Running `LaTeX' on `test2' with ``pdflatex -synctex=1  -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" test2.tex''
/bin/sh: pdflatex: command not found
```

I've been googling this and know this is a fairly common problem, but for the life of me I haven't been able to implement a fix. From what I've read it seems Emacs has a different `PATH` than terminal, no? Can someone please explain to me how to fix the `PATH` or `environment variable` (I'm not sure which) so that Emacs can find pdflatex. Is there something I need to change in my `~/.emacs`?

Comment: You run emacs in the terminal and it outputs a pdf? You mean you run latex in the terminal?

Comment: yes latex, my mistake.

Comment: This isn't really a TeX question, but an emacs question.  Here are some solutions: [EmacsApp](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsApp#toc2). I *don't* recommend using the `environment.plist` solutions, as they can interfere with other applications.  The "quick and ugly" solution seems the best; you need to change the path accordingly (the path there assume Darwin Ports). For MacTeX you want to make sure that `/usr/texbin/` is early in the path. (You also might want to try [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/).)

Comment: finally got it!

Comment: If you have found a solution please report it here as an answer of your own question, so everyone can enjoy of it

Comment: For mac users that might be googling the error 'LaTex: problems after [0] pages', if you just installed Mavericks you may have a different problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163849/mavericks-upgrade-screwed-up-my-pdflatex-command-not-found

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ok, sorry for the delay- i wasn't allowed to post a self-answer earlier.
Indeed Emacs.app was operating in a different environment than the terminal.

`M-x getenv` for `PATH` showed that `/usr/texbin` was missing, which explains why LaTex was not working inside the Emacs.app shell.

following @Alan Munn's idea to stay away from editing a .plist I found some [good info here](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_env_var_paths.html)
and hacked together this in `~/.emacs`

```lisp
(getenv "PATH")
 (setenv "PATH"
(concat
 "/usr/texbin" ":"

(getenv "PATH")))
```

`/usr/texbin` is now part of the`PATH` and LaTeX will play nice with Emacs.app

In El Captain, PATH changed. So you should use `which latex` in terminal to decide the real location. In my machine, it returns `/Library/TeX/texbin/latex`, so I should use `/Library/TeX/texbin/` instead of `/usr/textbin'.

thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 4):

There is an emacs package for dealing with this problem on OSX called `exec-path-from-shell`.  You can install it via the `list-packages` interface.  You need to activate it with

```
(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
```

in your emacs init file.  See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10722/2710.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to add in your .emacs the following command:

```lisp
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("YOUR/PATH/TO/LATEXB/BIN/")) )
```

Comment: I tried this earlier and unfortunately it didn't work. It's frustrating because I thought this would do the same thing as my fix in the answer post.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the root right, you can add the path to the end of `/etc/profile` like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/work/tools/arc/arcanist/bin:/work/tools/jdk1.6.0_25/bin
```

I have the same problem in my Linux/Ubuntu 12.04, and it works!