# Emacs doesn't recognize the latex commands (pdflatex, etc.) after installing MacTeX

Tags: emacs, mactex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pdflatex fails within Emacs.app, but works in terminal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24510/pdflatex-fails-within-emacs-app-but-works-in-terminal)

I installed MacTex on my Mac running Lion, but emacs is not able to run the latex functions (like pdflatex) to compile a .tex file. I know My latex installation works because I am able to generate pdf's with TexWorks that comes with MacTeX. However, I'd like to do so within emacs.

Can someone help me with that? I must probably update my PATH but I wasn't able to find the exact procedure.

Thanks!

Comment: @egreg Yes, I adex /usr/texbin to my path according to the link you gave me, and it worked. Feel free to close this question.