# Mavericks upgrade screwed up my pdflatex (command not found)

Tags: pdftex, emacs, auctex, mac

so everything was working fine ... until i upgraded to os x mavericks (version 10.9.2) a couple days ago.

using

- emacs version 24.3 (9.0)
- auctex version 11.87.3

after upgrade, tried to compile and got:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `test' with ``pdflatex  -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" test.tex''
/bin/sh: pdflatex: command not found

LaTeX exited abnormally with code 127 at Wed Mar  5 09:45:28
```

where did my pdflatex go? what is the fix?

Comment: Presumably the `texbin` setup that `mactex` usuall  installes got wiped during the upgrade. I've also seen this happen with `TeXLive` on windows 8 that was then updated to 8.1. The PATH addition was lost. Sadly I do not know which programmes to run on the Mac to get those paths (and `texbin` setup again). Have you searched the HD to see if `pdflatex` is still in the system folder?

Comment: what does `echo $PATH` say? And I'm not sure, but try `ln -s /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin /usr/texbin`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @daleif There is no 'system folder'. Certainly none which should house `pdflatex`. Perhaps you are thinking of traditional Mac OS (through Mac OS 9.*)?

Comment: This is what I use in my `.emacs` file for Snow Leopard:  `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/texbin"))`  Try also generating a latex document from Terminal.app without using Emacs to see if your TexLive installation is intact.  If it is not, then reinstall TexLive.

Comment: @cfr, by system folder I'm of course referring til the folder(s) where programs is placed on a mac. Tl is installed by root on the mac, so the files end up in the system folder hierarchy. I do not remember where. These folders are hidden from the user if you are using finder to browser (unless you go through Go). Might be easier to just run a "find" on the command line

Comment: i think the `ln -s` solution by @SeanAllred has worked. things appear to be going all right now.

Comment: @daleif OK. But 'system folder' is misleading in a Mac context because it means something different. Also *most* of TL is *not* stored in the hierarchy where system programmes are stored (or, for that matter, where third party .apps are stored). Most of it goes under `/usr/local/` which is explicitly system-independent. That's why the `ln -s` solution can work. Although link under `/usr` is gone, the distribution in `/usr/local` and the Mac config under `/Library` remains.

Comment: The simplest workaround is to change the path to your distribution in Preferences of Tex Live utility.

Comment: This seems to be happening with Sierra as well.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> **Note:** users on more recent versions of macOS will not be able to follow these instructions due to new restrictions introduced in those versions. See comments for workarounds.

It seems that the upgrade wiped the link from your Library (where MacTeX puts your actual TeX distribution) into your `/usr/texbin`.
You can reinstate this link with the following:

```
ln -s /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin \
      /usr/texbin
```

This will essentially create a shortcut at `/usr/texbin` that points to your `texbin` in MacTeX's internal directory.  You still should make sure that `/usr/texbin` is in your `PATH` environment variable, though.

NB. If you use DVI → PS → PDF, you may also need to repair the link to Ghostscript:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gs-noX11 /usr/local/bin/gs
```

Comment: my `echo $PATH` says `/usr/texbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. Is this all right?

Comment: @MichaelWBratton Looks solid. :)

Comment: @SeanAllred: Many thanks. +1. Just posted a follow up question on this [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177010/checking-and-removing-multiple-mactex-installaions).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Terminal & when I tried to do this I got a "permission denied" error (despite being logged in as admin). After a quick search, I found that you can either precede the command with 'sudo' or, if it was the last command entered, then you can just type 'sudo !!' and it'll prompt you for your password. After this, it worked perfectly for me. Thank you!

Comment: Those running the El Capitan beta might find this useful: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/196226/87067
(sorry, this comment will become redundant after release)

Comment: This is for El Capitan users!
[Pdf for Settings](https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf)

Comment: I've just upgraded to Sierra (OS 10.12), and this command does not seem to work for me.  sudo doesn't help.  got message "ln: /usr/texbin: Operation not permitted".  If I go into /usr I can't even make a directory texbin with mkdir.

Comment: @Joel see the comments above concerning El Capitan (which unilaterally removed write access to these directories).

Answer (score 18):

For those less comfortable with the command line: I had this problem after upgrading to OSX 10.9.2 as well.  After the upgrade, in my `/Applications/TeX/` directory I found a FixMacTeX2013.pkg.  Running this fixed the `pdflatex` issue.

Comment: I tried this, didn't work!

Comment: This just added the links to /Libraries/TeX/texbin After this I added the /Libraries/TeX/texbin to $PATH

Answer (score 5):

The suggestion

```
ln -s /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin \
      /usr/texbin
```

did not quite work for me, because in my `/Library/.../Programs` I do not have the directory `texbin`, but rather two directories: `i386` and `powerpc`.  I have an Intel processor and thus used:

```
ln -s /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/i386 \
      /usr/texbin
```

which worked fine.

Comment: Casualty of autocorrect: the command that worked is:  ln -s /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/i386 /usr/texbin

Comment: I fixed the appearance of code and also changed `Texan` to `texbin`. You can always edit your own (and also others') posts. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: $ sudo ln -s /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin \
>       /usr/texbin
ln: /usr/texbin: Operation not permitted

Comment: $ ln -s /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/i386 \
>       /usr/texbin
ln: /usr/texbin: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 2):

First go to the TeXworks preferences to add /usr/Texbin to the path. May cure the problem without having to create the symbolic links.

Comment: This is rather a comment than a comment

Answer (score 2):

In summary, all you have to do is to add `/usr/texbin` to the environment variable `$PATH`. Using Terminal you can do it in 3 steps:

1) Ensure that pdflatex command is installed in `/usr/texbin`

```
mac:yourname$ ls /usr/texbin
afm2tfm          dvired           initex           luaotfload-tool  mktexlsr         simpdftex        texluajitc
allcm            dvitomp          kpseaccess       luatex           mktexmf          synctex          thumbpdf
allec            ebb              kpsepath         makeindex        mktexpk          teckit_compile   tlmgr
allneeded        etex             kpsereadlink     man              mktextfm         tex              updmap
bibtex           extractbb        kpsestat         mf               mpost            texconfig        updmap-sys
dvi2fax          fmtutil          kpsetool         mf-nowin         mptopdf          texconfig-dialog xdvi
dvilualatex      fmtutil-sys      kpsewhere        mfplain          pdfetex          texconfig-sys    xdvi-xaw
dviluatex        gftodvi          kpsewhich        mft              pdflatex         texhash          xdvipdfmx
dvipdfm          gftopk           kpsexpand        mkindex          pdftex           texlinks         xelatex
dvipdfmx         gftype           latex            mkocp            pktogf           texlua           xetex
dvipdft          gsftopk          luajittex        mkofm            pktype           texluac
dvips            inimf            lualatex         mktexfmt         rungs            texluajit
```

2) Print the old `$PATH` value

```
mac:yourname$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

3) If `/usr/texbin` is not part of $PATH value you can append it by adding or editing your `.profile` file (needs superuser permissions)

```
mac:yourname$ sudo vi /Users/yourname/.profile

...
\#This is the concerned part of .profile
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/usr/texbin
...
```

After saving the file, you can restart Terminal or open a new window/tab.

Answer (score 0):

The document I am working on has a compile system that runs pdflatex and I hit the same problem. I just downloaded and installed MacTeX on Mavericks, which added `/usr/texbin` to my `PATH`, which contains 23 links to `pdftex`, however `pdflatex` is not one of them.  The following fixed it for me:

```
cd /usr/texbin
ln -s pdftex pdflatex
```