# Checking and removing multiple MacTex installations

Tags: installing, mac, mactex

I was having the same problem as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163849/mavericks-upgrade-screwed-up-my-pdflatex-command-not-found). However, at that time I just reinstalled the MacTex, and things started to work.

As MacTex takes huge space on the disk, I want to make sure that I haven't installed multiple instances of the application, any ideas on how to do that?

And in case I find multiple instances, how do I remove the old installation!

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! :) This is how you see the distributions installed: http://imgur.com/a/wemy7 Do you see multiples?

Comment: yes... i do see multiples..

Comment: Similar to: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177010/checking-and-removing-multiple-mactex-installations

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The simplest way to check and remove older versions of MacTeX is through the terminal.  Open a terminal window and type:

```
cd /usr/local/texlive
ls
```

If you have multiple years of TeX Live installed, you will see directories corresponding to each of the older years.  For example, you may see:

```
2012     2013     texmf-local
```

which would indicate that you have both TeXLive 2012 and 2013 installed.  You can then safely remove the `2012` directory in the following way (must be done from an administrator account):

```
sudo rm -rf 2012
```

Do this for any other years you may have lying around. The only other thing to be deleted are the local runtime directories. These are usually not very big (perhaps 100 MB or so). They are found in your local `~/Library/texlive` folder. Since these are local to your account you don't need to be an administrator to delete them so you can use:

```
cd ~/Library/texlive
rm -rf 2012
```

Alternatively, you can navigate to the folder in the Finder by using Command-Shift-G (Go to Folder in the Go menu) and just drag the appropriate folder(s) to the Trash.

If you have multiple users on your machine, you would need to do this for each user.

Comment: (+1) I would add that you want to make sure that all MacTeX links are in order when you do this; it's very easy to get broken links with this method if you aren't careful.

Comment: @SeanAllred With a standardly installed MacTeX I've never had a problem. The TeX Distribution Pane is smart enough to sort out the links, I think.

Comment: +1. Thanks a lot to both of you for all the effort. I was able to locate and remove the old installations! Much appreciated!!

Comment: There are also runtime directories in `~/Library/texlive/` (usually not too big). Also `rm -fr ~/Library/texlive/2012`  is thus necessary for removing really everything. Without the terminal, open a Finder window, press Command-Shift-G and type `/usr/local/texlive` in the box that appears; then drag the `2012` folder to the trashcan; the Finder will ask for permission.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>(Change 2017 below with the last year you have on your system)</sub>

1. Open a Finder window
2. Hit Command-Shift-G (or menu Go > Go to folder…)
3. In the box that opens type `/usr/local/texlive`
4. Hit Return and something like below will appear

[image]

5. Trash the folders with the years you no more want
6. The system will ask for an administrator password, fill it in and click OK
7. Check that the 2017 version still works good
8. Empty trash
9. Good bye old versions

Be sure to leave untouched the folders `2017` and `texmf-local`.