# Cannot start Texshop after system upgrade (to 10.12.6) and installation of newest Texshop

Tags: installing, texshop

I get:
Reason: Incompatible library version: TeXShop requires version 1.6.0 or later, but Sparkle provides version 1.5.0

I am aware of the answers to similar problems:

- [Texshop not working after upgrade to Sierra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/380664/2693) and
- [Checking and removing multiple MacTex installations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/177010/2693)

and did delete older versions of TeXShop as well as runtime directories.

However the problem persists.

Comment: What version of TeXShop are you using? Are you sure you really removed all old versions of TeXShop since that message makes it appear you have an old version still around? Have you tried to reboot to clear out any caches in memory?

Comment: Hello Herb, As in questions/177010, I wrote and got: cd /usr/local/texlive
MINEDI722110:texlive carstennielsen$ ls
2017  texmf-local
MINEDI722110:texlive carstennielsen$ I checked texmf-local and it was updated the same day I installed the new version of Texshop so I suppose I should not delete it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is MINED...  is that part of your prompt? I'm not sure I understand what you did. What version of TeXShop are you trying to use? Did you really remove /usr/local/texlive/2017?

Comment: Let me add, what OS version sis you update from? And finally, do you lots of very old software around tha used Sparkle to update itself but hasn't been updated in a long time?

Comment: Thanks again, Herb for your interest. Earlier I removed texlive/2010 but I have retained the newly installed texlive/2017. "MINEDI722110:texlive carstennielsen$" is the response when I write "cd /usr/local/texlive" in the terminal. Then I write "ls" and get "2017  texmf-local" which I guess is the list of items in texlive (I am not well versed in programming fundamentals). I seek to use the newest version of texlive. A technician updated from the 2010 OS to Sierra and it is very possible that I have old software from my back-up (would removing Texworks help?) But how to find it? Thanks!

Comment: How did you determine there were no more old versions of TeXShop.app on your computer?

Comment: I write "cd /usr/local/texlive" in the terminal. Then I write "ls" and get "2017 texmf-local" Before I got  "2010 2017 texmf-local" if I remember correctly. Basically, I just followed the steps (including how to delete the 2010 version) from questions/177010 . But maybe I should also delete TexWorks (which must be somewhere else)? Thanks again!

Comment: Try to use Spotlight to look for TeXShop.app and see if it finds more than one version. You might also install Find Any File, which is free and just search for TrXShop.app.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and solved it by following a combination of Herb's advice:

1. I searched for TeXShop using Spotlight-- the computer found several
   versions that were not showing up in the finder
2. I trashed all of the versions I could find
3. I rebooted and reinstalled

Thanks, Herb!