# After upgrading to OS X Yosemite I cannot run xelatex

Tags: mac

When compiling TeX files that compiled OK before the upgrade I get an error message `-bash: xelatex: command not found`. I have not changed my `PATH`:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/richard/.iraf/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
```

Comment: You did not change your path, but maybe your OS did (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208181/why-did-my-tex-related-gui-program-stop-working-in-mac-os-x-yosemite). Please post the output of `echo $PATH` and `type xelatex`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You might find a related issue by looking at questions with the tag [osx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx). If you are trying to launch `xelatex` from a GUI program, [Adam Maxwell's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208182/23160) seems relevant.

Comment: Can I ask the close votees for clarification what exactly makes this question off-topic? Since it clearly deals with LaTeX, it would be very appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: I'd see if the FixMacTeX2014.pkg package in /Applications/TeX repairs things first. It's been required for me after two different OS upgrades. See also [Mavericks upgrade screwed up my pdflatex (command not found)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171291/3345).

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, here's how `/usr/texbin` winds up pointing to `/usr/local/texlive/2014`:

```
/usr/texbin -> ../Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs/texbin
/Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs/texbin -> ../.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin
/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin -> x86_64
/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/x86_64 -> ../../../../../../../usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin
```

I'm pretty sure OS upgrades will wipe out local changes to the file system, excluding home directories and /usr/local. But there's enough changes that MacTeX makes in /usr, /Library, etc. that could get wiped. I've always used FixMacTeX(version).pkg after every OS upgrade, and it's always worked.