# After migration to MacOSX 10.11 "El Capitan", how to run simple utilities such as "texdoc" and "kpsewhich"?

Tags: mactex, mac

Last night, I migrated my MacBook's operating system from 10.10 "Yosemite" to 10.11 "El Capitan". Everything seemed to go smoothly. Happily, regarding my TeX-related work, I am able to use the GUI front ends "TeXworks" and "TeXshop" just fine since completing the OS upgrade. I use MacTeX2015, with all the latest updates installed.

Oddly, though, since completing the upgrade I can no longer run any MacTeX command-line utilities such as `texdoc` and `kpsewhich`. (Actually, as I just discovered, I can no longer run `pdflatex` either *from a command line*. However, I never do run `pdflatex` from a command line prompt, so that's not an urgent problem for me -- at least not for now.)

The suggestions given in the posting [Mavericks upgrade screwed up my pdflatex (command not found)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163849/5001) do not seem to be applicable to this case, as they all seem to revolve around setting up `/usr/texbin` correctly -- `/usr/texbin` is no longer allowed under MacOSX 10.11. The document [MacTEX-2015 and El Capitan](http://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf) by Herb Schulz deals in depth with adjusting settings in the GUI front ends, but it appears not to touch on what to do about `/usr/texbin`, which appears to be the now-missing link to TeX's command line utilities.

Pointers and solutions most welcome!

Comment: No El Capitan here yet, but have you tried simply adding the new 'flexible' location `/Library/TeX/texbin` to the list available in `/etc/paths.d`? That's where the 'magic' happens. (I've got for using the normal *nix approach of just adding the real binary location to my path for other reasons.)

Comment: @JosephWright - There are currently three files in the directory `/etc/paths.d` (all three world-readable but only root-writeable): `40-XQuartz`, `TeX`, and `git`. The content of the file named `TeX` is a single line, `/Libary/TeX/bin`. Do I need to modify the file called `TeX`?

Comment: That's the right setting for El Capitan: it should but `/Library/TeX/bin` into your path, and its there that the real links should be. What does `echo $PATH` give, and if it's in the path what about `ls -l /Library/TeX/bin` and `command -v pdftex`?

Comment: @JosephWright - Happily, the directory `/Library/TeX/bin` contains all the correct symbolic links. The source of the problem, then, appears to be that (a) the file `.profile` (or, equivalently, I suppose, `.bashrc`) didn't include the string `/Library/TeX/texbin` in the definition of `$PATH` and (b) for some reason, the information in `/etc/paths.d` wasn't being "taken" by MacOSX 10.11. For now, I think I've solved the problem by adding `/Library/TeX/texbin` to the definition of `$PATH`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as clear from comments the issue is related to Mac OS X 'picking up' `/etc/paths.d` data which has been set correctly at the 'TeX end'.

Comment: @mico Did you ever solve this problem? I just updated to El Capitan and had the same problem which turned out to be an old path in `/etc/profile`.

Comment: @AlanMunn -- I ended creating a file called `~/.profile`, which contains only the following line: `export PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`. I left `/etc/profile` unmodified; that file continues to point to  (in two steps) to `PATH="$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin`. Indeed, `/usr/texbin` no longer exists under El Capitan. Note that with `~/.profile` in place, `/Library/TeX/texbin` is searched *first*.

Comment: @mico Ok. My machines typically have multiple users, so I prefer not to have per user profiles for stuff that should be available to all users.  I removed the old code that was in `/etc/profile` and replaced it with `eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)` within the `whoami != "root"` conditional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be caused by some leftover junk from previous versions of TeXLive which at one point added the path `/usr/texbin` to the `/etc/profile` file (the global `/bin/sh` profile).

The default `/etc/profile` on current version of the MacOS should be the following:

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

If your `/etc/profile` contains code to add `/usr/texbin` to the `PATH`, you should remove it.  You should not replace the code with `/Library/TeX/texbin`, but instead remove the code entirely and make sure the `/etc/profile` file correctly executes the `path_helper`, which is the proper way for paths to be modified in OS X.

You can also solve this problem locally, by modifying your `~/bash_profile`, to add `/Library/TeX/texbin` to your path, but then you will need to do this for each user on your system if you have multiple users.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer! I've updated the file `/etc/profile` on my system (and deleted `~/.profile`, since it's no longer needed), and things are working fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can not use `/usr/texbin` anymore.  This is a final change.  Every program relying on that link needs to be fixed.  I think this is what Herb Schulz' file also tries to say.

Another change is that `/usr/sh` won't run non-signed programs anymore.  So the `/usr/sh pdflatex` that emacs is trying won't work:

```
#/bin/sh pdflatex
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex: cannot execute binary file
```

while:

```
#pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) ...
```

This may be Apple's fix for recent reports of [Gatekeeper breakouts](http://www.macrumors.com/2015/09/30/mac-exploit-bypasses-gatekeeper/).

Comment: I apologize for not having expressed myself more clearly: I am aware that `/usr/texbin`  is *verboten* under MacOSX 10.11. My question is, what to do?

Comment: When you do a fresh install of MacTex 2015, it will create all the symlinks in `/Library/TeX/texbin/`, so you can add that to your `PATH` variable. MacTeX also tries to do that upon installation, but maybe you are using a different shell? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: When I type `echo $PATH`, I get `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin`. Looks like something got badly clobbered! I use the `bash` shell, just in case that matters.

Comment: The duplicates should not hurt, although it would be good to debug why they are there. I have `/Library/TeX/texbin` in my path, and I'm not adding it manually in any user local config files. It's globally added to PATH my MacTeX. Do you have MacTeX 2015?

Comment: Yes, I have MacTeX2015. (I mentioned it in the first paragraph of my posting.)

Comment: Just add it to your path in your shell init file. If you have not changed your shell, it is `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/.bashrc`. Google for "change PATH variable" if you run into trouble.

Comment: @Mico From your comment on the question it looks like you've got the right data for Mac OS X to get the path right, but for some reason it's not 'taken'. That's a Mac problem rather than a TeX one.

Comment: Interestingly, there was no file named `.bashrc` -- or `.cshrc`, for that matter -- in my home directory. (I do know how to find "invisible" files.) May I ask you to edit your answer to focus on getting the PATH variable set up to include `/Library/TeX/texbin` -- I'll be glad to upvote and acccept your posting.