# latex under emacs would not work with El Capitan

Tags: mactex

i have update to El Capitan, but latex would not work the error message problems after [0] pages. To see the problem i have got.
/bin/sh: pdflatex: command not found
I tried to understand what was the error in Path, but i did not figure it out 
any help, i am not an advanced user!!
thanks in advance

Comment: Is TeX/LaTeX installed at all?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270490/how-to-use-auctex-in-macos-el-capitan help?

Comment: @egreg the OP doesn't seem to be using Emacs, how's the solution there relevant?

Comment: @yo' The general problem is the same, but maybe we need a better go-to question here, as this issue is currently quite actively sought-after. Plus the OP's self-answer does suggest use of Emacs quite heavily.

Comment: Please refer also to https://www.tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html and the links therein.

Comment: @yo' I just read the title

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by changing the `PATH` in my `.emacs` file.
The `PATH` should be like this

```lisp
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/texbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:" (getenv "PATH")))
(setq exec-path (append '("/usr/texbin" "/Library/TeX/texbin") exec-path)
```

so just all what you have to do is paste these two lines in your `.emacs` file and comment out the old two lines