# Emacs-AucTex - Preview-PDF2DSC exited abnormally with code 127 - I can't see preview-latex

Tags: emacs, auctex, elisp

## Context:

I am a Newbee on Emacs and AucTex. I just get started several days ago and installed some packages as some tutorials go along.

I installed some packages: `company`, `swiper`, `auctec`, `auto-complete-auctex`, and `counsel`. In particular, `auctex` has version 12.2.0.

## My Problem:

I installed it yesterday, and I could do C-c C-a to preview it entirely. However, I cannot do preview-latex (C-c C-p C-p). It gives me error with lots of "under construction triangles":

[image: What I see]

```
TeX Output exited as expected with code 1 at Thu Apr 23 00:21:29
Running `Preview-PDF2DSC' with ``pdf2dsc _region_.pdf _region_.prv/tmpQ3JlTM/preview.dsc''
/bin/sh: pdf2dsc: command not found

Preview-PDF2DSC exited abnormally with code 127 at Thu Apr 23 00:21:29
PDF2DSC sentinel: Opening input file: No such file or directory, /myworkingdirectory/_region_.prv/tmpQ3JlTM/preview.dsc
```

It generates several files in my working directory:
[image: My working directory]

The directory it referring has no file in it. And this is the corresponding elisp code, and yes, I checked latex is in that folder path.
[image: My elisp code]

## Update 1:

I did not install `ghostscript`. After I installed, the problem is still exist.

## Update 2:

I found this answer really helpful [How to use Auctex in MacOS El Capitan?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270490/how-to-use-auctex-in-macos-el-capitan)
At least for Mac OS Catalina, one shall use

```
;; Auctex configurations
(setenv "PATH" "/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin/:$PATH" t)
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/Library/TeX/texbin")))
```

to set the environment path.

Shout out to @frougon for his patience on me! His code also works

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin" "/Library/TeX/texbin")))
```

Comment: Log says it can't find pdf2sc. Did you made TeX installation? If so, check, whether this pdf2sc binary is installed. Remember your TeX AucTeX doesn't ship with TeX, you need to install *TeX binaries on your own, using a TeX distro (texlive, mictex, protext… can't remember the name of the Mac devoted one).

Comment: @sztruks I’ve installed LaTeX (MacTex) and maybe MikTex already. I used to use TexStudio and rmarkdown before emacs. I’ve checked I do have LaTeX installed..

Comment: But do you have pdf2dsc installed? Look in your distribution for this peculiar binary.

Comment: On my Debian system, `pdf2dsc` comes from the `ghostscript` package.

Comment: @frougon I found out I did not install `ghostscript`. I installed it from homebrew, yet still not working. Also, there is nothing inside `/myworkingdirectory/_region_.prv/tmpQ3JlTM/` folder.

Comment: @sztruks I did not. Where can I find pdf2dsc? I did not find it on homebrew and melpa. I installed `ghostscript` from homebrew, but it does not help.

Comment: @YuchenZhang Do you see a `pdf2dsc` executable on your filesystem and do you still have the `pdf2dsc: command not found` error message? If so, it might be a `PATH` issue or AUCTeX configuration, however I fear don't  know MacOS enough to be of much help.

Comment: @sztruks Ok it is a command from `ghostscript`. I will try to restart my computer see if it works.

Comment: @frougon I have pdf2dsc on terminal! It recognizes it belongs to `ghostscript`

Comment: @frougon pdf2dsc belongs to /usr/local/bin/ while I set Auctex's path to /Library/TeX/texbin/, which is where my latex distributions are.

Comment: @YuchenZhang 1) Do you still have the error message I quoted? 2) You can add the directory you need to the PATH, just use the `:` separator, e.g. `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") "/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin"))`. Test the result with `M-: (getenv "PATH")`.

Comment: (or the other way around, if you want `/Library/TeX/texbin` to take precedence)

Comment: @frougon 1) I do not have error messages. pdf2dsc is in /usr/local/bin/ and it works via terminal. 2) I got you.

Comment: 1) I know it works in terminal. My question is, do you still have this error message when generating previews under AUCTeX, as your question shows? 2) `M-:` is `Meta-:`. If you don't know your Meta key (?!), try Alt, but you can also do Esc *then* `:`. I was just suggesting to add `/usr/local/bin` to the PATH setting from your question (although I find it strange that `/usr/local/bin` is not already in Emacs's PATH; maybe you should first print the PATH from within Emacs). In order not to have paths duplicated due to the `concat`, this would require an Emacs restart, to keep things simple.

Comment: @frougon I tried your idea, and it kind of works. However, now it is saying `/bin/sh: pdflatex: command not found`, but pdflatex is in /Library/TeX/texbin. And yeah, it is still generating errors....

Comment: Please give the output of `M-: (getenv "PATH")`. You can copy it from the `*Messages*` buffer after it has been echoed, or you can do `C-j` immediately after `(getenv "PATH")` in the `*scratch*` buffer; then you'll have the output in the same buffer.

Comment: @frougon I am sorry. I am new to this. I tried M-:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin and the other way around. One gives me this `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable /usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin)` and blabla, one gives me `eval-expression: Symbol’s value as variable is void: /Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Don't be sorry, but where did I suggest to do `M-:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin`? Of course this is invalid... Do what I said in the `*scratch*` buffer. You noticed the Buffer menu? :-) Also `C-x C-b` and `C-x b`... `C-j` is Control-j, maybe Control is the Command key for you?

Comment: @frougon Ohhhh I got you... here is the path `"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_10:/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec-x86_64-10_10/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/bin"`

Comment: You see the `.../libexec-x86_64-10_10/Library/TeX/`. You are apparently just missing the `:` separator before `/Library/TeX/texbin`. In your config, where you did the above changes. Maybe restart Emacs after adding the `:`.

Comment: Do I need to add `/usr/local/bin` again? This gets me to where I began. `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/Library/TeX/texbin/"))  
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/Library/TeX/texbin/")))`

Comment: @frougon Thank you for your help! I found this answer really useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270490/how-to-use-auctex-in-macos-el-capitan

Comment: @frougon Thank you for your patience. I appreciate it!

Comment: I was reading about `exec-path`. [This](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/550) seems helpful. According to your output, I would do: `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin"))` and `(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin" "/Library/TeX/texbin")))`.

Comment: @frougon Yours works for me! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear that, you're welcome.

Comment: I'd suggest to remove the trailing `/` in `(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin" "/Library/TeX/texbin/")))` in your edit of the question, it's a bit ugly. :-)

Comment: @frougon Haha for sure

Comment: One more thing: with this config, `/usr/local/bin` takes precedence over `/Library/TeX/texbin`. This is somewhat consistent with the fact that your PATH starts with `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` (system paths). Should you have the same executable in  `/usr/local/bin` and `/Library/TeX/texbin`, and wish that the latter takes precedence (because maybe it would provide a newer version of the program(s) than what you have in `/usr/local/bin`), you might want to swap the paths (in both of the relevant Emacs config lines).