# Suddenly TexShop won't compile anything. What to do?

Tags: compiling, mactex, texshop

I use TexShop in a Mac computer. Suddenly (after I transferred some file I compile with another program in another computer) TexShop won't compile anything. I include the picture with its message.[image]

Can someone tell me what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: either pdflatex isn't installed or you have el capitan  version of the OS and they changed things: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270485/after-migration-to-macosx-10-11-el-capitan-how-to-run-simple-utilities-such-a

Comment: I do have El Capitan indeed. This must be the problem since I had none before that.

Answer (score 1):

The default path for interpreters on El Capitan has changed to:

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
```

Try changing the path in the TeXShop to this one.

You can confirm this on your machine by running `which pdflatex` in terminal.