# kpsewhich problem after updating to "El Capitan"

Tags: errors, textmate

I'm having this problem which was discussed in other topics, but I think I'm not following the steps to solve it correctly.

Problem when compiling in Textmate:

```
This command requires ‘kpsewhich’ which wasn’t found on your system.

The following locations were searched:
 • /usr/bin
 • /bin
 • /usr/sbin
 • /sbin
 • ~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/bin
```

I went to the terminal and wrote:

```
find / -name kpsewhich* -print
```

With results:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/universal-darwin/kpsewhich
/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin/kpsewhich
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/kpsewhich.1
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/kpsewhich.man1.pdf
/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/universal-darwin/kpsewhich
/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/kpsewhich
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/kpsewhich.1
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/kpsewhich.man1.pdf
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you check out the posting [After migration to MacOSX 10.11 “El Capitan”, how to run simple utilities such as “texdoc” and “kpsewhich”?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270485/5001) In particular, do try to add the line `export PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH` to the file `~/.profile`. (If `.profile` doesn't exist yet in your home directory, just create the file.) Then, log out and log back in to fully update the PATH variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have installed MacTeX 2015, you should go to the preferences of TextMate and change them so they look like

[image]

Use the `+` button if `PATH` doesn't appear.

Comment: Works perfect now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you use an old version of the [LaTeX bundle](http://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle/issues). Please check that you installed the most recent version in `Preferences→Bundles…`.

You **do not need to set `PATH`** for “Typeset and View (PDF)“ – or the other commands of the LaTeX bundle – to work at all. If you still need to make this change, then that is a **bug in the bundle**. Please file an [issue](https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle/issues) in this case so I can fix it. Thank you!