# TeXLive with TextMate -- Documents have suddenly stopped compiling

Tags: texlive, textmate

I just tried to compile a document and got this message:

```
This command requires ‘kpsewhich’ which wasn’t found on your system.

The following locations were searched:
 • /usr/bin
 • /bin
 • /usr/sbin
 • /sbin
 • ~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/bin
 • /usr/local/bin

If ‘kpsewhich’ is installed elsewhere then you need to set PATH in Preferences → Variables to include the folder in which it can be found.
```

I've been away and haven't really used TeX in a while; I *think* there were upgrades to TextMate and possibly TeXLive before I left town, but I don't remember.

Following the TexLive documentation, I created a new `texmf.cnf` file, placed it in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c`, and tried to run `sudo -H mktexlsr`, only to be told `command not found`. Now I'm stumped. How can that command not be found? What is the remedy?

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292536/kpsewhich-problem-after-updating-to-el-capitan

Comment: Yes! Closing question.

Comment: Nice to know! Happy TeXing!