# Compile Latex in Emacs.app with AucTex

Tags: emacs, mac

I installed emacs 24.5 and auctex 11.88 on os 10.9. The compilation (C-c C-c) of a tex file does not work in the GUI (Emacs.app), but it does work in the terminal. I get the following error
[image]

I believe that I set up the necessary paths because the preview functionality is working. Not sure what else to try. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: How did you install `TeX` itself ?.

Comment: This is most likely a problem with the shell environment.  The emacs package `exec-path-from-shell` addresses exact that type of problem on OSX.  Just install it via the `list-packages` interface and call `(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)' in your emacs init file.

Comment: See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10722/2710

Comment: Possible duplicate on this site is http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24510/15925

Comment: Thanks, Andrew! The exec-path-from-shell did the job. Although the installation did not work as the instructions of the git repo suggested.

Comment: @AndrewSwann – feel like making that an answer? :)

Comment: @SeanAllred I think we should mark this as a duplicate of the other question on own site.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Ah, I didn't catch your [other comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277041/compile-latex-in-emacs-app-with-auctex?noredirect=1#comment667036_277041)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the Aquamacs package for Emacs on OSX.  Peoples opinions will vary, but it's really a nice Mac friendly setup. I don't think it has the same problems setting up the path.